# Did I correctly express what I ate for dinner?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を

I wanted to say "Tonight I ate pizza and french fries."

My attempt was 「今夜私はピザとフラドポテトを食べた。」

I'm unsure of a few things (I'm early in my learning of Japanese).  I'm unsure if I correctly used the verb 「食べる」, and the particles 「は」and 「を」.  And was using 「と」 correct for "and," since it was linking two nouns?

Would my translation be a natural way to say my statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me, french fries is spelled フラ**イ**ドポテト. Don't forget the イ :).

[Time-word, subject は object を verb] is a perfectly good sentence structure and と is great to join two nouns that form the object!